# Double editable callbacks

Tags: tabulator

Tabulator 4.9.3

I have a table with one column that has an `editable` callback defined as follows:

```
{ field: "name", title: "Name", editor:"input", editable:function(cell){
        return confirm( "Are you *SURE* you want to edit the name?" );
    }
},
```

If I click on the cell, the confirmation dialog gets fired twice.  Is this expected? (Dialog opens, I click cancel, dialog opens again, click cancel, dialog goes away)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the editable function is called both on mouse button down and mouse button up in newer versions of Electron (I encountered this in 15).

Fortunately, you can use [built-in callbacks](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/callbacks) to check if mouse pointer is on the cell:

```
cellMouseEnter: function (e, cell) {window.is_mouse_on_cell = true;},
cellMouseLeave: function (e, cell) {window.is_mouse_on_cell = false;}
```

Then check before calling the editable function:

```
editable: function (cell) {
    if (window.is_mouse_on_cell) {
        return confirm( "Are you *SURE* you want to edit the name?" );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

I presume the author is actively working on the next major version of Tabulator, so this is unlikely to be fixed in 4.9.

Also, while Electron implemented alert and confirm, they are blocking. If you encounter freezes (can be triggered by the double call here), try [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog).